# Does socket orientation have an effect on sound?

Tags: power, audio, amplifier

Is it possible that the socket orientation (in Europe: one pin 230V, the other ground) can have an effect (albeit very small) on the amplifier behavior of a very old stereo sound system? What is, if any, the underlying reason ?

Comment: Europe switched eons ago from 220V~ to 230V~, but I often hear people talk about 220 still.

Comment: @stevenh "240V" is common here.

Comment: @stevenvh 220 V is still used in some countries.

Comment: @Thomas @Andreja, I would be impressed if the power company could keep a +/-5% tolerance on line voltage.

Comment: @Nick T Mine can't. :( Anyway the whole point is that there are just two popular voltage ranges. The one around 230 V @ 50 Hz and the one around 115 V @ 60 Hz, so it's irrelevant if the voltage is actually 220 V or 230 V or 240 V.

Comment: @Andreja - Did you really mean 230V @ 60Hz?  In the US, we get 115/110/120 by taking half of the 230/220/240V input.  In fact, half of the 120VAC circuits in my house are out of phase with the others.  One is precisely half of the other, and the frequencies are identical.

Comment: @reemrevnivek  In large part of the world, the frequency is 50 Hz, so I meant 230 V @ 50 Hz. Take look at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_with_mains_power_plugs,_voltages_and_frequencies) chart. Only few countries actually use 230V @ 60Hz.

Comment: There's always a tolerance on it. It used to be 220V for most of Europe and 240V for the UK before it was changed to 230V nominal, +/- 10%.

Answer (score 1):

I can think in one effect but only for a very specific hardware. If You're using a [capacitive supply](http://electroschematics.com/5678/capacitor-power-supply/) with a [half-wave rectifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier#Half-wave_rectification) - In this case the circuit ground is connected directly at one of the socket pins. If this pin is the ground its ok. If this is the 220 AC, although the circuit still operates, you may have some noise coupled on the circuit via ground, as your new ground is oscilating at 60Hz with a amplitude of 220 volts
.

Comment: Noise and loss of sound quality was indeed one factor I spotted in a blind experiment. My friend made a pattern of positions, while I listened to the produced sound with speakers in another room. I felt a difference, although really small.

Comment: Your amp doesn't use a capacitive supply.  That's kind of a hack for low-power electronics.  Also, this noise wouldn't be very audible while playing music, just would introduce some hum during silence.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine this could introduce some unexpected ground loops and so increase both hum and noise levels. - especially if the amp is connected to other kit with hot (live) and neutral (connected to ground/earth) wired the other way round.